# Starting a different task from Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, stack

My app can be opened from two different contexts:

(1) From the home screen
(2) From a notification in the title bar.

If the app is opened from the notification, it starts Activity B, and hen the user is done with this activity, **I would like to close out of the app.** I don't want it to return to another activity in the activity stack if the app has been opened previously from context (1) above.

For example, if I open the app from the home screen, then press home, and then open the app from a notification in the title bar, when I am done with Activity B it takes me back to the main activity for my app. I don't want it to do this.

I would really like to be able to start the activity stack afresh when I open the activity from a notification.

I have tried adding the flags

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

But this doesn't seem to help. Alternatively, I also tried setting noHistory="true" inside the activities in my app, but this *really* doesn't work well if the user opens the app from context (1).

Any ideas? Is there any way to start the activity stack fresh when you open the app from a different context?

Answer (score 0):

You could call `finish()` from the `onStop()` method of ActivityA that way when the user is inside of this activity and presses the home button the activity will finish and no longer be on the stack. Then when they open ActivityB from the notification bar and get done with it they will be taken back to the homescreen (or another activity if they were inside of something when they opened you from the notification bar).

Comment: I don't think that would work in the case of

A -> B -> C (press home screen)

I would have to do that from every activity in my app, right?

Comment: Im not sure that I understand what you mean. Do you mean you are inside ActivityA, and you open ActivityB from the notification bar without leaving ActivityA? If thats what you mean then I think this will still work, because onStop() in A is still going to get called and it will finish A, then when you are done with B you'll go back to whatever you had before A, or homescreen if nothing.

Comment: No, I mean that I have many different activities in my app. Let's call them {A,B,C,...,G}. What I meant was that from any of these activities, the user could press the home button. Let's call the current activity the user is in activity X. If the press the home button from X, and then subsequently open the app from the notification bar, Activity B will be launched, then they close activity B, and they will be returned to activity X. Instead I want the activity stack to be cleared and the app to exit.

Comment: Ahh ok, Yes you'd need to put finish() inside the onStop() methods for every activity except ActivityB (although putting it in activityB wouldn't change the behavior at all if my understanding of things is correct)

Answer (score 0):

In the AndroidManifest, you should add `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` for Activity B. It means that it will start a new task for activity B each time it is launched.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't seen that before. I'll try giving this a shot. Just a quick question: On http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear, do you know what is meant by "root activity"? Is it referring to the activity that has this flag set, or is it referring to the main activity of the app?

Comment: The root activity is the one which has LAUNCHER category. It is not the activity set with this flag.